# How to manage more than one detail section in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm setting up a Crystal Report for POS receipt and there are two detail sections, one for products and other for services. The problem is that products and services are overlapped: for example, first a product row shows up and then a service row. I want to show only products in detail section a and then in detail section b services. I want to print the POS receipt on a thermal printer. Is there any alternative way to print the receipt a on thermal printer, continuously print the receipt?

I tried two detail sections, but they show the data like this:

```
product 1   qty    price
service 1          price
product 2   qty    price
service 2          price
```

I want to show the results like this:

```
Product 1  qty   price
Product 2  qty   price
service 1        price
service 2        price
```

Answer (score 0):

create two sub reports one for products and other for services.

Now in detail section a place product sub report and in detail section b place services sub report